# indentation error in python class constructor

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Following code compiles without any error:

```
class game:
    def __init__(self, filePath):
            self.gameState = readGame.readGameState(filePath)
```

But when I modify it to

```
class game:
    def __init__(self, filePath = None):
        if filePath is None:
            self.gameState = [[0 for x in range(7)] for x in range(7)]
        else:
            self.gameState = readGame.readGameState(filePath)
```

Here the intention is to call class constructor with or without filePath. The file contains 7x7 matrix and hence I've initialized game state with empty matrix if filePath is not passed. But I am getting IndentationError: expected an indented block. what's fundamentally wrong here. I've tried hard but not able to debug it.

Comment: Looking at your indentation, they are all indents made of spaces, except the last line which has one tab character in it. try re-indenting that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces in the last line -

```
self.gameState = readGame.readGameState(filePath)
```

It shows that it has first 4 spaces, then a tab and then again 4 spaces, whereas all other lines you have only use spaces for indentation.

You should not be mixing tabs and spaces , I would advice you to consistently use spaces for indenting that line as well.

Comment: Hi are you pointing out that in last line of first code? even I noticed that but that runs correctly. The code below is what I wrote after modifying given code which to me looks correctly space indented. But it throws indentation error.

Comment: No I am pointing to the last line of second code only , try removing all indentation in that line and try indenting again.

Comment: "tab" and "space" are not even technical terms; but code formatting should not be used for technical terms - it should be used for text that appears **as-is, in the code**.